# Maven error when building Neo4j community edition from source

Tags: maven, neo4j

I am trying to build Neo4j from https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j.git. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 (32-bit), Maven 3.0.4 and Oracle JDK 1.7.0_45.

I am building it under the parent POM, using

```
$ mvn clean install -DminimalBuild -Dlicense.skip=true
```

The build fails, however:

```
enter code here------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Neo4j - JMX support 2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Neo4j ............................................. SUCCESS [0.683s]
[INFO] Licensing configuration ........................... SUCCESS [1.783s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel ..................... SUCCESS [24.188s]
[INFO] Neo4j - JMX support ............................... FAILURE [0.033s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Usage Data Collection ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Graphviz generation ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Lucene Index .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Graph Algorithms .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Graph Matching ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Cypher Compile 1.9 ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Cypher Compile 2.0 ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Cypher .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Community ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Community ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Generic shell ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Examples .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Server API .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Server ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Server Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Server Plugin Tests ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Community Build ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Graph DB Monitoring and Management tools .. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Advanced .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Advanced Server ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Advanced Build .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Communication Package ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Clustering Infrastructure ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Consistency Checker ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Backup Tool ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - High Availability ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Enterprise .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Enterprise Server ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j - Enterprise Performance Tests .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Enterprise Build ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 29.571s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 23 18:16:07 BST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 42M/301M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project neo4j-jmx: Could not resolve dependencies for
project org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.neo4j:neo4j-
kernel:jar:tests:2.0-SNAPSHOT in http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots/
was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
interval of neo4j-snapshot-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I have had the same problem running it under Windows 7.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is now resolved. The community/jmx project had a dependency on the community/kernel test-jar which is only built after the jmx project. Being a Maven noob, I'm not sure if Maven is supposed to get the dependencies from the snapshot repository or not. Anyway, I have the artifact locally now.

Comment: How did you get the articact locally?

Comment: Well, in fact the problem was that running -DminimalBuild doesn't build the test jars for the projects. I had to use -DskipTests to actually compile the test code and have artifacts installed locally. The problem was not the build order.